# how to search with MongoClient exeptuating a data Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am searching for several data, but I want one not to appear.

Example:

```js
const info = [{
    idn: 1,
    parent: 1
}, {
    idn: 2,
    parent: 2
}, {
    idn: 3,
    parent: 3
}]
```

what I need is:

```js
const info = [{
    idn: 2,
    parent: 2
}, {
    idn: 3,
    parent: 3
}]
```

this is my code to search

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").Mongoclient;
const URI = "mongodb://localhost:20017"

MongoClient.connect(URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, async (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const data = await client.db("baseGeneric").collection("genericInfo").find({}).toArray();
    console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$ne`

```
db.collection.find({
  idn: {
    $ne: 1
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo play ground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_jS4l3j7nB8)**

There are multiple ways you can do, you can use `aggregation()` of `find()`. Suppose you decide that few of the id cannot participate when fetching, you can use `$nin`

Answer (score 0):

yea, that fuction but with _id didnt work

```
const recipes = await client
            .db(DBU)
            .collection("data_travel")
            .find({"vdn":{$ne:data.vdn},"skill":{$ne:data.skill}}).toArray();
```